# Salesforce Community Third Party Bolt templates - Where are they?

Tags: community, lightning, customer-community, community-builder

Im a VF developer just getting into Communities.  I have created a couple of Communities off of the Napili template, but I was looking for other templates to play with.

In the Dreamforce keynote and other articles, I keep seeing pictures and mentions of 3rd party Bolt templates that will be available.  I cant find them.  Is this a License issue, or are they just not out yet?

Quote:

> Leveraging their rich industry knowledge, more than 10 partners have
>   created Salesforce Bolt solutions for some of the most popular use
>   cases across multiple industries. In addition, a new Lightning Bolt
>   category on the AppExchange will allow the thousands of partners in
>   the Salesforce ecosystem to not only develop, but market and sell
>   Salesforce Bolt solutions. Here are two mentions

I also cant find the Bolt section of the AppExchange.

https://www.salesforce.com/products/community-cloud/features/accelerate-customer-collaboration/

http://investor.salesforce.com/about-us/investor/investor-news/investor-news-details/2016/Salesforce-Introduces-Lightning-Bolt-a-New-Framework-that-Empowers-Companies-to-Accelerate-the-Creation-of-Communities-Next-Generation-Portals-and-Customer-Facing-Websites/default.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_change_log.htm?edition=&impact=):

> **[Package Lightning Bolt Solutions More Easily](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_networks_bolt.htm)**
>
> Availability of Lightning Bolt solutions on AppExchange is postponed until a later release.

Comment: If this link answers the question, please cite relevant content here. Links can break over time, so when a link constitutes the entire answer it's less durable in the long run.